# How to use nested SELECT statements in sql?

Tags: mysql, alias, derived-table, nested-select

I have two tables as

**Book**

```
+------+--------------+--------+----------+
| bkey | bname        | nochap | b_id     |
+------+--------------+--------+----------+
|    1 | Let Us C     |     17 | luc13    |
|    2 | OOP with C++ |     17 | oopwcpp6 |
+------+--------------+--------+----------+
```

and

**luc13**

```
+------+-----------------+---------+
| cnum | cname           | c_id    |
+------+-----------------+---------+
|    1 | Getting Started | luc13gs |
|    2 | C Instructions  | luc13ci |
+------+-----------------+---------+
```

so, as you can see that the table name of second table (**luc13**) is the element of first table **book**. So while displaying the second table, i don't want to specify it's name, so I write the query

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT b_id FROM book WHERE bkey = 1)
```

and its shows error,

**ERROR 1248 (42000): Every derived table must have its own alias**

So I searched it and write the query again

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT b_id FROM book WHERE bkey = 1 AS custom)
```

Now the error is removed but still the output is

```
+-------+
| b_id  |
+-------+
| luc13 |
+-------+
```

So I think only `SELECT b_id FROM book WHERE bkey = 1` is executed.
So is there any way to display my table **luc13** without directly specifying its name ?

Comment: yep. I read all that. I still don't know what you want.

Comment: I want to display my second table without specify its name directly, means its name should be came from table 1, by using nested SELECT statement, but it didn't worked

Comment: Yes, dynamic SQL is your way to go.

Comment: Can you tell me the query

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use a [**`prepared statement`**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html) for this:

```
SET @s := CONCAT('SELECT * FROM ', (SELECT b_id FROM book WHERE bkey = 1));

PREPARE stmt FROM @s;

EXECUTE stmt;

DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Comment: Thanks Betsos, it worked well, but still I want to Know some things just for knowledge,is this the character variable `@s` ?,  which you have store the query.
And are these statements are the part of dynamic sql or what ?